# A Hilbert class field that is not contained in the Hilbert class field of any imaginary quadratic field.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I realize that this question may be very wild and unusual.

> Is every Hilbert class field, contained in a Hilbert class field of an imaginary quadratic field?

I think the answer is probably no. If the answer is no, can anyone give an explicit counter-example?

> Give a counter-example for the above statement: Give a field whose Hilbert class field is not contained in the Hilbert class field of any imaginary quadratic field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and let $H$ be its Hilbert class field. Then $\mathrm{Gal}(H/K)$ is abelian, since it is isomorphic to the class group of $K$.

Since $K/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, $H$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$ whose Galois group sits inside a short exact sequence
$$1\to A=\mathrm{Gal}(H/K)\to \mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbb Q)\to B = \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)\to 1,$$
where $A$ is an abelian group and $B\cong C_2$.

There are plenty of fields that cannot be a subfield of $H$ and, if $L$ is not a subfield of $H$, neither is its Hilbert class field.

An explicit example is the splitting field of $f(x) = x^5 + x +1$ over $\mathbb Q$, whose Galois group $S_5$ is not solvable.

Comment: Exposing my ignorance about CFT here. Why is $H/\Bbb{Q}$ Galois? This does not hold for all abelian extensions of quadratic imaginary fields.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that's a good point! If $K/\mathbb Q$ is a number field with Hilbert class field $H$, then it's not true in general that $H/\mathbb Q$ is Galois (e.g. take any non Galois extension $K$ with class number $1$). But it is true if $K/\mathbb Q$ is Galois: any Galois conjugate of $H/\mathbb Q$ is also an abelian unramified extension of $K$.

Comment: Indeed! :-) ${}$